# trigger to class

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I am converting the below trigger to apex class but while saving the class "Compile Error: Invalid identifier '    '. Apex identifiers must start with an ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by any number of ASCII letters (a-z or A-Z), digits (0 - 9), '$', '_'. at line 2 column 1" can anyone help me where it went wrong.

Trigger :

```
trigger duplicatechecktrigger  on Case(before insert,before update) {

map<string, Case> caseMap = new map<string, Case>();

for(Case csold: system.trigger.new){

if((csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c!= null) && (system.Trigger.isInsert || (csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c == system.trigger.oldMap.get(csold.id).FrCCC_Delivery__c))){



    if(caseMap.ContainsKey(csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c)){
        csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c.addError('The case already has the same delivery number');
    }else{
        caseMap.put(csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c, csold);
    }
}


for(Case csdup: [SELECT CaseNumber, FrCCC_Delivery__c FROM Case WHERE FrCCC_Delivery__c IN : caseMap.keySet()]){
    Case newCase= caseMap.get(csdup.FrCCC_Delivery__c);



         newCase.FrCCC_Delivery__c.addError('The case '+csdup.CaseNumber+' already has the same delivery number');


    } 


}

}
```

Apex Class :

```
public class DupClass{
     public void checkdups(Case[] ca) {
       map<string, Case> caseMap = new map<string, Case>();
          
      for (Case csold : ca) {

if((csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c!= null) && (csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c == oldMap.get(csold.id).FrCCC_Delivery__c)){


   if(caseMap.ContainsKey(csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c)){
        system.debug('The case already has the same delivery number');
    }else{
        caseMap.put(csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c, csold);
    }
}
         for(Case csdup: [SELECT CaseNumber, FrCCC_Delivery__c FROM Case WHERE FrCCC_Delivery__c IN : caseMap.keySet()]){
    Case newCase= caseMap.get(csdup.FrCCC_Delivery__c);

           system.debug('The case ' +csdup.CaseNumber ' already has the same delivery number');


     }

    } 
       }
}
```

Comment: 'Trigger.oldMap is a map of IDs to the old versions of the sObject records. You cannot use 'oldMap' directly in Apex class like you used in trigger.

Comment: You need to pass the oldMap values into the Apex class as a map variable in the class with a method the trigger is calling.

Comment: have you just copy and pasted thje code?  that is the reason it;'s showing.please edit it  by you own.

Comment: this blows up due to a SOQL query inside of a for loop. Will fail on the first dataloader with 101 records

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would start indentig your code.

Second you need to send oldMap to checkdups method.

Third: check the query for cases, you should avoid this because it is inside a for loop.

Just fixing the missing parameter and a problem on string concatenation you may have something like this:

```
public class DupClass{
    public void checkdups(Case[] ca, Map<Id, Case> oldMap) {
        Map<String, Case> caseMap = new Map<String, Case>();

        for (Case csold : ca) {

            if((csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c!= null) && (csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c == oldMap.get(csold.id).FrCCC_Delivery__c)){
                if(caseMap.ContainsKey(csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c)){
                    System.debug('The case already has the same delivery number');
                }else{
                    caseMap.put(csold.FrCCC_Delivery__c, csold);
                }
            }

            for(Case csdup: [SELECT CaseNumber, FrCCC_Delivery__c FROM Case WHERE FrCCC_Delivery__c IN : caseMap.keySet()]){
                Case newCase= caseMap.get(csdup.FrCCC_Delivery__c);

                System.debug('The case ' + csdup.CaseNumber + ' already has the same delivery number');
            }

        } 
    }
}
```